# Purple screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: login-screen, gdm, 21.10

Couldn't log in because the `gdm3` login screen has no password field, see screenshot:

[image: gdm3 login screen]

The unability to switch from current session to the TTY3 text console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> didn't work here) forced me to restart in recovery mode in order to select `lightdm` instead of `gdm3` using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

which did work fine.

I retried:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

after having uninstalled `gdm3` with:

```
sudo apt purge gdm3
```

and reinstalled with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -y gdm3
```

with no success. The same blank login screen is still there.

Any clue would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.: Error message on upgrade day (never seen before):
`nov. 04 07:21:06 jhn gdm3[1738]: Gdm: Failed to list cached users: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.11 was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: I had the exact same issue, including TTY not working, and wasn't able to solve it.  I didn't upgrade, I did a clean install.  I'm wondering what's common between us? i9-9900K, RTX 2080Ti, 64GB RAM.  Using ethernet cable.  In the USB slots I had a keyboard, mouse and XBox Wireless Adapter, did you have anything extra plugged in?

Comment: Laptop here, wifi, nothing plugged in.   
X11 instead of Wayland.  
Other similar cases [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=purple+screen+21.10) and apparently not any lasting solution for the moment.  

Maybe a next update (kernel or other) will bring the solution otherwise we'll have to wait for Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: For your information, the installation of most recent kernel 5.15 did not solve the problem.